# Function not returning value when called

Tags: scala

So, I'm a bit new to Scala, and I don't really understand how it reads code, compared to other languages.

Take this simple example:

```
@main
  def roll():Int =
    var x:Int = (math.random*6+1).toInt
    return x
  def print = 
    for i <- 1 to 10 do 
      println(roll())
```

The above code returns nothing, however, should I flip the methods (put print "method" before "roll"), it will now work. I find this incredibly strange. Where have I done wrong? I just simply want to call a method/function that randomizes a number, and print it using a new function to call it. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: This seems to work as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/uEp4iB4ZQTK8XUSJK7qIUg/2

Comment: Do not use `var` or `return` (except in very specific case which are far from being such a simple code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`@main` annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html) is applied to method (one, the following after it), i.e. for :

```scala
@main
def roll():Int =
  var x:Int = (math.random*6+1).toInt
  return x

def print = 
  for i <- 1 to 10 do 
    println(roll())
```

Your main method will be `roll` and only it will be invoked during program execution. And `print` is just a declared method which is not called.

And when you "flip them":

```scala
@main
def print = 
  for i <- 1 to 10 do 
    println(roll())

def roll():Int =
  var x:Int = (math.random*6+1).toInt
  return x
```

`print` becomes the main method, so it is invoked and it calls the declared `roll` method in the loop.

Also read [annotations doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/annotations.html).

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense! I also understand that there are two ways of using main method, either extend app, or like how I did. Which is the better way and why?

Comment: @FreezeAim Was glad yo help. From the linked doc (first link) -_"`@main` methods are the recommended way to generate programs that can be invoked from the command line in Scala 3"_. If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of the answer)

Comment: Half of the confusion seems to be caused by indentation. Why would you indent the main method differently than the `@main`-annotation in the first place? The documentation actually suggests putting it in the same line as the `def` itself, then it would be entirely unambiguous what the `@main` is referring to.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yeah, I know. I just tried that to see if maybe my code would work (before posting all this). After trying Guru's method, it worked! I have since removed the indentations